# Template10 - Full Screen (Menu Hamburger)

Tags: c#, uwp, template10

I am develop an UWP app, and I am using Template 10. When the app is in full screen (Windows 10 Desko, the hamburger menu appears open.
Is it possible to put it closed when it is in full screen?
I've been looking for all the code and I do not find this option!

Comment: this a function of the adaptive triggers for the screen.  You can alter them in the as you need but some of it is baked logic.  Really I would not get to use to the control, it will be deprecated soon.

Answer (score 0):

> When the app is in full screen, the hamburger menu appears open

As @mvermef said, this feature is defined by the [`Adaptive​Trigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.adaptivetrigger) of hamburger menu. You could find following `VisualStateGroup` inside the template 10 control [`HamburgerMenu`](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Template10/Template10.Hamburger/Controls.HamburgerMenu/HamburgerMenu.xaml).

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup" CurrentStateChanged="VisualStateGroup_CurrentStateChanged">
    <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateNarrow">
        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <AdaptiveTrigger x:Name="VisualStateNarrowTrigger" MinWindowWidth="{Binding VisualStateNarrowMinWidth, ElementName=ThisPage, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </VisualState.StateTriggers>
        <!--  see code-behind  -->
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateNormal">
        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <AdaptiveTrigger x:Name="VisualStateNormalTrigger" MinWindowWidth="{Binding VisualStateNormalMinWidth, ElementName=ThisPage, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </VisualState.StateTriggers>           
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateWide">
        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <AdaptiveTrigger x:Name="VisualStateWideTrigger" MinWindowWidth="{Binding VisualStateWideMinWidth, ElementName=ThisPage, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </VisualState.StateTriggers>           
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

When the windows size become wide than 1200, the `VisualStateWideTrigger` of `HamburgerMenu` will be triggered so that the menu open.

> Is it possible to put it closed when it is in full screen?

So that if you want to prevent this you can set `VisualStateWideDisplayMode` to `Inline` or `CompactOverlay` for `HamburgerMenu` control.

```
<Controls:HamburgerMenu x:Name="MyHamburgerMenu"   VisualStateWideDisplayMode="Inline">
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I know this is set by the `Adaptive​Trigger` of hamburger menu, but I dont know where is code. Where is this code: `<Controls:HamburgerMenu x:Name="MyHamburgerMenu"   VisualStateWideDisplayMode="Inline">`

Comment: @FernandoSousa, Please try Ctrl+F search `HamburgerMenu` in your solution. How you create your template 10 app, I mean from which template?

Comment: Template Hamgurger

Comment: @FernandoSousa, if you are using `Hamgurger` template, you should find the `<Controls:HamburgerMenu>` in `Views->Shell.xaml`. Then add the property as I showed above.